# Angular Google Maps Not Showing up in my Template View?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular Google Maps and have followed the configurations as well as the steps given on the site. I dont get any error as well as neither the map loads up on the directive. The code is as follows:-

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'uiGmapGoogleMapApi',
    function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
        //Variables Decleration
        $scope.odorizerID = "";
        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -73
            },
            zoom: 8
        };
        //Function Decleration
        $scope.onMapClick = function(odorizerID) {

        }

        uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {

        });

    }
]);
```

**app.js**

```
app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    'uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {

        /**
         * Configuring the Google Map API.
         */
        uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            //    key: 'your api key',
            v: '3.17',
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
        });



        /*For any unmatched url, redirect to / */
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        /*For all the other states we would configure the $StateProvider*/
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "/app/views/auth/login.html",
                controller: 'AuthCtrl'
            })
            .state('maps', {
                url: "/maps",
                templateUrl: "/app/views/maps/maps.html"
            })
            .state('performance', {
                url: "/performance/:ororizerID",
                templateUrl: "/app/views/details/performance.html",
                controller: "PerformanceCtrl"
            })
            .state('usage', {
                url: "/usage/:ororizerID",
                templateUrl: "/app/views/details/usage.html"
            });
    }
]);
```

**maps.html**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

**index.html**

This is included in the index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
```

Please help me resolve the same. Map does not load at all.

The output that I get in the view is

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><div class="angular-google-map"><div class="angular-google-map-container"></div><div ng-transclude="" style="display: none"></div></div></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

**style.css**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; width:800px;}
</style>
```

Comment: I just noticed you haven't set up a controller in your `$stateProvider`. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Should work after that. It's weird that it's always the last thing we check even if it's such an obvious mistake :p

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your controller declaration on your `$stateProvider`.

```
.state('maps', {
    url: "/maps",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/maps/maps.html"
})
```

-->

```
.state('maps', {
    url: "/maps",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/maps/maps.html",
    controller: "MapCtrl"
})
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Any chance you could create a JSfiddle to replicate the problem?

Comment: I wont be able to port it to fiddle... does it require key?

Comment: Not sure. Can you edit your post to include your css, just in case?